# how to include diferrent swing items to main class from another class

Tags: java, swing

I am quite new to java. I have created a GUI window with some jlabel , jtextfield. But recently for a project I need to create another class with those jlabel and jtextfield and need to display them to main class. But I dont know how to do that. I have seen this tutorial , but it has covered only with jmenu (not jtext field and jlabel) .

[Adding Swing components from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934783/adding-swing-components-from-another-class)

my code is below,

public class common_items extends JFrame {
  public void item_gui(String labelForMatrix) {

```
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);


  JLabel lbl = new JLabel(labelForMatrix);
    lbl.setBounds(5, 5, 424, 14);
    lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(lbl);

    JTextField txt2 = new JTextField();
    txt2.setBounds(178, 117, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(txt2);
    txt2.setColumns(10);

    JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();
    txt1.setColumns(10);
    txt1.setBounds(178, 64, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(txt1);

    JLabel lblRowNumber = new JLabel("Row number");
    lblRowNumber.setBounds(189, 39, 67, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblRowNumber);

    JLabel lblColumnNumber = new JLabel("column number");
    lblColumnNumber.setBounds(155, 95, 119, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblColumnNumber);
     }
   }
```

I have tried to display  them to main class but it fails . my main class code is below

```
    common_items itm=new common_items();
    itm.item_gui();
```

Plzz suggest me what should I do .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, you are trying to make a main `JFrame` class that includes components from other classes like the `JLabel` or the `JTextArea` that connect to the class and use them as normal components.

So what you need to do is just create a main class (not the JFrame) and make a JFrame class (call it mainFrame for example) and then just create the components class (e.g textArea JLabel ...) and then you just represent these classes as variables in the frame class (which we will be executing from the main class).

and maybe you just understand code better than speech:

**Main** class to start the program (load the frame class which contains everything)

```
public class Main {

    public Main(){
        //execute the frame
        new Frame();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main(); //execute the function that launches the JFrame
    }

}
```

**Frame** class which (obviously) contains the frame

import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5151041547543472432L; //ignore this it is just the serial id of the JFrame you can omit this line from your code

    ComponentsStorage cs = new ComponentsStorage(); //display class as variable so we can use it more efficnent 

    public Frame(){
        launch(); //execute function
    }

    public void launch() { //launch
        setTitle("Frame Demo");//title
        setSize(640, 480);//size (width * height)
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//close when close button is pressed

        //you can just do ComponentStorage.tf.blah blah blah... but it is much easier as a variable
        cs.label.setSize(500, 500); // you can mess up witht the components you stored there
        cs.tf.setSize(40, 5); //as you can see here I am just adding the components by 

        //add them here
        add(cs.label);
        add(cs.tf);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);//by setting this you place the screen always in the middle of the screen
        setVisible(true);//there is no point of creating JFrames if they aren't visible
    }

}
```

And just another class that stores the components (JLabel, JTextField...) that you want to use (it can be any class that just contains these things even if there are other functions in it I named it **ComponentStorage**)

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ComponentsStorage {

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();

}
```